# Magento, Icon Packs, CName Records and Cloudlfare

Tags: html, css, magento, cloudflare, icon-fonts

I am currently running a Magento Store through Cloudflare and I have been experiancing duplicate orders which some stack overflow users have suggested is due to Cloudflare. In order to test this, while still using my Cloudflare subscription to some extent, I decided to create CName Records (eg: cdn1.mydomain.com) for my Media, Skin and JS files and have cloudflare only serve these resources.

It seems to be going well except I am getting strange behavour with FireFox browsers.

My styles get linked to the page correctly with the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn1.mydomain.com.au/skin/frontend/theme/default/css/styles.css">
```

In my style sheet I link to my font packs with the following code (from IcoMoon):

```
/* BEGIN Install Custom Icons from IcoMoon */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icons';
    src:url('../fonts/icons-v8.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/icons-v8.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/icons-v8.svg#icons') format('svg'),
        url('../fonts/icons-v8.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/icons-v8.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This all works perfectly fine with cloudflare enabled on my root domain and when it is disabled, however, when I turn it on for cdn1.mydomain.com.au, my icons in FireFox no longer load. They do however load in Chrome with no problems.

When looking at the net tab in fire bug, I can see that Fire Fox is indeed finding and downloading the font pack as it responds with a Success Header(200 OK).

Is there anything I am missing as to why FireFox would struggle with showing the font pack?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with something like Rocket Loader. Does turning off that feature in your performance settings - if on - fix the issue?

The fact that issue is in one browser and not the other suggests to me an optional performance feature possibly impacting something).